# How does ObservedObject subscribe to its @Published members

Tags: swiftui, observers, combine

I am trying to write my own `@Published` like property wrapper - I have hundreds of member values that I would like to only emit publication values when they actually change equality-wise (as opposed to every time they are set, which is default)

The property wrapper itself is straightforward

```
@available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
@propertyWrapper public struct EqPublished<Value: Equatable> {

    public var wrappedValue: Value
    {
        willSet {
            _projectedValue.send(newValue)
        }
    }
    public var projectedValue: AnyPublisher<Value, Never>
    private var _projectedValue: CurrentValueSubject<Value, Never>

    public init(wrappedValue: Value)
    {
        self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue
        self._projectedValue = CurrentValueSubject<Value, Never>(wrappedValue)
        self.projectedValue = _projectedValue.removeDuplicates().eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Which can be used with something like

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @EqPublished var value = 5
}


// In some view later on 
@State var count = 0
...
Text("El Tappo")
        .onTapGesture {
            // Update every 3rd tap
            self.count = (self.count + 1) % 3
            self.model.value = self.model.value + (self.count == 0 ? 1 : 0)
        }
        .onReceive(self.model.$value) { val in
            print("Value is \(val)")
        }
```

Works as expected - the `onReceive` gets fired on the 3rd tap with a 6. Replace `EqPublished` with `Published` and its called every time.

However - if I change the consuming view to be

```
Text("Value is \(model.value)")
        .onTapGesture {
            // Update every 3rd tap
            self.count = (self.count + 1) % 3
            self.model.value = self.model.value + (self.count == 0 ? 1 : 0)
        }
        .onReceive(self.model.objectWillChange) { _ in
            print("Model")
        }
```

The `objectWillChange` publisher never fires and the UI will never recalculate - if I change the `@EqPublished` to a plain `@Published` it all works.

**The question(s) - updated for deeper understanding**

- How does the `ObservedObject` class connect itself to its publishing members?
- When does the connection take place? (I think in the accessor of `objectWillChange` from looking at the headers)
- Is there some sort of reflection that can be done to inspect each member and connect without caring what the `Value` type of `Published<Value>` is?

Answer (score 1):

Should have stuck with it a while longer - this is somewhat possible (albeit not in the same fashion as `Published`)

The following code updates the above code to include a `Void` type `valueWillChange` publisher to allow the same flow to work. And I didn't realise Swift had reflection built in with `Mirror`.

I can't say I know how `ObservedObject` works *without* an overarching protocol or a somewhat-hidden publisher for a Void value - or perhaps how to cast it out as a `Published<Value>` type without knowing what `Value` is (or ignoring it)

This would also not be hard to adapt to any other conditional that might be needed (less than, value-validation, etc)

```
class Model: EqObservableObject {
    @EqPublished var valueEq = 5
    @Published var valueAlways = 5
}

@available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
public class EqObservableObject : Combine.ObservableObject {

    private var eqValuesChanging: [AnyCancellable] = []

    init()
    {
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        for child in mirror.children
        {
            if let value = child.value as? EqPublishedProtocol
            {
                eqValuesChanging.append(
                    value.valueWillChange.sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] in
                        self?.objectWillChange.send()
                    })
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

public protocol EqPublishedProtocol
{
    var valueWillChange: AnyPublisher<Void, Never> { get }
}

@available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
@propertyWrapper public struct EqPublished<Value: Equatable>: EqPublishedProtocol
{

    public var wrappedValue: Value
    {
        willSet 
        {
            if wrappedValue != newValue 
            {
                _valueWillChange.send()
            }
        }
        didSet
        {
            if oldValue != wrappedValue
            {
                _projectedValue.send(wrappedValue)
            }
        }
    }

    public var projectedValue: AnyPublisher<Value, Never>
    public var valueWillChange: AnyPublisher<Void, Never>
    private var _projectedValue: CurrentValueSubject<Value, Never>
    private var _valueWillChange: CurrentValueSubject<Void, Never>

    /// Initialize the storage of the Published property as well as the corresponding `Publisher`.
    public init(wrappedValue: Value)
    {
        self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue
        self._projectedValue = CurrentValueSubject<Value, Never>(wrappedValue)
        self.projectedValue = _projectedValue.eraseToAnyPublisher()
        self._valueWillChange = CurrentValueSubject<Void, Never>()
        self.valueWillChange = self._valueWillChange.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

And updated UI code to show its usage

```
      HStack {
            Text("ValueEq is \(model.valueEq)")
            .onTapGesture {
                self.count = (self.count + 1) % 3
                self.model.valueEq = self.model.valueEq + (self.count == 0 ? 1 : 0)
            }
            .onReceive(self.model.$valueEq) { val in
                print("ValueEq is \(val)")
            }

            Text("ValueAlways is \(model.valueAlways)")
            .onTapGesture {
                self.count = (self.count + 1) % 3
                self.model.valueAlways = self.model.valueAlways + (self.count == 0 ? 1 : 0)
            }
            .onReceive(self.model.$valueAlways) { val in
                print("ValueAlways is \(val)")
            }
        }
        .onReceive(self.model.objectWillChange) { _ in
            print("Object Changed")
        }
```

Comment: Does the `objectWillChange` publisher emit to subscriber for mutation of both `valueEq` & `valueAlways` in the usage? I think it prints **Object Changed** only for `valueAlways` change but the mutation of `valueEq` doesn't print.

Comment: Both `valueAlways` and `valueEq` are upstream of `objectWillChange` - the only difference between `valueAlways` and `valueEq` is in the suppression of duplicated values in `valueEq` via `.removeDuplicates()`, and the fact that __somehow__ `valueAlways.projectedValue` can emit to `objectWillChange` without a manual hookup or an overarching protocol. The automatic mechanism of connection is what I am interested in

Comment: Also updated the code a bit to properly do the lifecycle - `EqPublished::valueWillChange` should trigger the `objectWillChange` before the actual change occurs - this is reflected in the `didSet`. Also removed the `removeDuplicates` with a simple equality check to keep them both in the same spot

Answer (score 0):

Though I'm not to answer the actual question of **How does ObservedObject subscribe to its @Published members?**, I can show you different approach than [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59674511/3687801) for what you want to achieve.

---

If I'm not mistaken, you are trying to subscribe to `objectWillChange` publisher for your custom property wrapper type. By default `@Published` wrapper does that for you automatically. For that to work with your wrapper type, you will just need to call `send()` on the `objectWillChange` manually. Therefore, you need to subscribe to the publisher (projected value) of the property wrapper you defined and then call the `send()` method on the available `objectWillChange` publisher.

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @EqPublished var valueEq = 5
    @Published var valueAlways = 5

    private var storage = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init() {
        $valueEq
            .sink { [weak self] _ in
                self?.objectWillChange.send()
            }
            .store(in: &storage)
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really what the question is about - `@Published` establishes the relationship between the `Published::projectedValue` and the `ObservedObject::objectWillchange` automatically - that is what I am trying to achieve. That requires reflection of some sort to do without hardcoding (as said, I have hundreds, approaching thousands of these equality based connections to do - hardcoding each one is ... not great)